# How to 100%width a div with centered content?

Tags: html, css, width

For example a site like facebook home page.

https://www.facebook.com/

the content is centered, but the background color is 100% width. How does one go about doing that ?

how do i go about doing that within a wrapper ?

Comment: What are you centering? Images, text, other elements? Do you require vertical as well as horizontal centering?  Various elements require some mildly different approaches in a pure CSS solution. Also, do you have browser target requirements, older versions of IE require some special treatment.

Comment: I want the content to be centered. but i want the background color to be 100%width for example facebook.

facebook top bar is 100% width, i know how to do that.

facebook content background color is 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a container element (body, for instance) that takes 100%. You can color it in any way you want.

Then you need another container (a  element) with a fixed width. Then add in the  section the following lines:

```
#div_id {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto; 
}
```

This code will set the fixed width of the content block, and specifying automatic margins for left and right. This is one easy way to center block elements in the page.

Comment: Or: margin: 0 auto; works the same, but less code :)

Comment: @Ruub that's correct. But I believe my code is more self-explanatory ;-)

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused, but im going to work with the code you gave and see what results i get.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on what @opalenzuela answered. His answer is perfectly acceptable, just spelling it out a bit more for you.

CSS:

```
body {
margin:50px 0px; padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#eee;
}

#Content {
width:500px;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:left;
padding:15px;
border:1px dashed #333;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="Content">
Put your content here.
</div>
</body>
```

Fiddle to play with:  http://jsfiddle.net/2mZeQ/

Answer (score -2):

I think it is not possible without wrapper element, or it is possible by using javascript (jQuery) and some size calculations and positioning but I think that **javascript is not the  way to go in this case**